# Pivot Wider in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this

```
rest_id task_name quarter nc
123     labeling  1       TRUE
123     labeling  2       FALSE
123     labeling  3       FALSE
123     labeling  4       FALSE
123     cooking   1       TRUE
123     cooking   2       FALSE
123     cooking   3       TRUE
123     cooking   4       FALSE
123     cleaning  1       TRUE
123     cleaning  2       FALSE
123     cleaning  3       TRUE
123     cleaning  4       FALSE
```

I want to pivot it to look like this

```
rest_id quarter labeling  cooking  cleaning
123     1       TRUE      TRUE     TRUE
123     2       FALSE     FALSE    FALSE
123     3       FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
123     4       FALSE     FALSE    FALSE
```

I've tried this:

```
X <- pivot_wider(df,
                 names_from = task_name,
                 values_from = nc,
                 values_fill = list(nc=F))
```

But it doesn't give me my intended output.. can someone help me?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue.  Even with creating that column name 'task_name' as a vector, it works for me because the function is looking for the object in the immediate environment first i.e. the data itself and not the parent env i.e. .GlobalEnv.

Comment: Is it based on the same data that you have an issue.  Can you try the data from my post.  It would be better to use `dput` so that the structure becomes clear for reproducibility.  Also, when you say that it doesn't give intended output.  What is the output you are getting

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to create a vector of column names for the wide format.  The `names_from`  is selecting from the 'task_name' column in the dataset and it creates the wide column name from the unique values of that column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = task_name, values_from = nc, 
           values_fill = list(nc = FALSE))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  rest_id quarter labeling cooking cleaning
#    <int>   <int> <lgl>    <lgl>   <lgl>   
#1     123       1 TRUE     TRUE    TRUE    
#2     123       2 FALSE    FALSE   FALSE   
#3     123       3 FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    
#4     123       4 FALSE    FALSE   FALSE
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(rest_id = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L), task_name = c("labeling", 
"labeling", "labeling", "labeling", "cooking", "cooking", "cooking", 
"cooking", "cleaning", "cleaning", "cleaning", "cleaning"), quarter = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), nc = c(TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Isn't this the exact same code as the OP said they tried?