# How do I merge data in R based on row values and create new variable with it?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, linear-regression, data-cleaning

I have a dataset in which every row represents sales of a particular product in a particular geography (see image 1). I want to take the price of other products and add them as additional columns so that they can be an additional variable in a regression (see image 2). How do I do this?

My current data:

[image: Current]

Desired output:

[image: Desired]

Comment: Does this answer help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402239/pivot-wider-in-r try something like `pivot_wider(df,
                 names_from = Product,
                 values_from = c(Volume, Price))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivot Wider in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402239/pivot-wider-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Use `gather`, `unite` and `spread` from `dplyr` package

```
df <- tibble(
          Time = rep(c("Week1","Week2","Week3"), 4),
          Geography = c(rep("Dallas",6), rep("Houston",6)),
          Product = c(rep("Apple",3), rep("Orange",3), rep("Apple",3), rep("Orange",3)),
          Volume = c(1403, 3514, 3388, 2284, 3091, 3558, 3199, 2521, 3381, 2127, 2383, 2469),
          Price = c(4.01, 4.11, 4.10, 2.63, 2.98, 2.25, 3.67, 3.80, 3.29, 5.30, 5.02, 5.57))

>df
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Time  Geography Product Volume Price
   <chr> <chr>     <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Week1 Dallas    Apple     1403  4.01
 2 Week2 Dallas    Apple     3514  4.11
 3 Week3 Dallas    Apple     3388  4.1 
 4 Week1 Dallas    Orange    2284  2.63
 5 Week2 Dallas    Orange    3091  2.98
 6 Week3 Dallas    Orange    3558  2.25
 7 Week1 Houston   Apple     3199  3.67
 8 Week2 Houston   Apple     2521  3.8 
 9 Week3 Houston   Apple     3381  3.29
10 Week1 Houston   Orange    2127  5.3 
11 Week2 Houston   Orange    2383  5.02
12 Week3 Houston   Orange    2469  5.57

df <- df %>%
  gather(Volume, Price, -(Time:Product)) %>%
  unite(temp, Product, Volume) %>%
  spread(temp, Price)

> df
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Time  Geography Apple_Price Apple_Volume Orange_Price Orange_Volume
  <chr> <chr>           <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Week1 Dallas           4.01         1403         2.63          2284
2 Week1 Houston          3.67         3199         5.3           2127
3 Week2 Dallas           4.11         3514         2.98          3091
4 Week2 Houston          3.8          2521         5.02          2383
5 Week3 Dallas           4.1          3388         2.25          3558
6 Week3 Houston          3.29         3381         5.57          2469
```

P/S: please copy a sample of data in your question next time (not the pictures). It helps others to replicate the problems and solve them faster.