# R Dataframe from Factors of Column

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe in R

[image]

I would like the dataframe to become

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: See this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402239/pivot-wider-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, pivotwider was what I needed.